# SPFx Deploy List with custom form using client side web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, custom-form, spfx

I have built a client side web part using SPFx. As part of the package I am also provisioning several site columns, content types, and lists. I want these lists to use the client side web parts as thier default "new" and "edit" forms but cannot figure out how to properly format the schema.xml file.

From my understanding it works likes this:

```
<Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" /> 
<Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" /> 
<Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" UseDefaultListFormWebPart="FALSE">
    <WebParts>
        <AllUsersWebPart WebPartOrder="1" WebPartZoneID="Main">
            <![CDATA[
            ]]>
        </AllUsersWebPart>
    </WebParts>
</Form>
```

However I have no idea how to properly write the CDATA component to bring in my client side web part.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I am unable to use Microsoft Forms or PowerApps because they are not currently available on the Government Community Cloud, which is why I am trying to do this with SPFx web parts.